So what's gone wrong?
I had some scrapes on the side of my car and decided to respray the door panel using some rattle  cans that I had made up by a paint supplier to match my car's colour.. Wet sanded first with 1500 paper. Then once dry, I applied 3 coats of the base paint and 2 coats of clear coat. So, today, I wet sanded the clear coat with 2000 paper then buffed first with compound and then polish. It looked ok at first but now it has turned to this below. What did I do wrong and are there any recommended fixes?
Thanks

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How long did you wait between painting and polishing?

I waited 24 hours and the weather is about 82F here and sunny.....

I can't really see in the image what's going on (I do see it as being hazy) so I can't give you direct advice, but would suggest you wait (if you haven't done so already) for the paint to harden fully, then try to do the cut/buff again.

Also, with a rattle can done for automotive paint, there's usually two parts, where you mix the paint and hardener together just before you use it. If this wasn't present, your paint is probably really soft and will be until it fully cures (where I was going in my other comment). If the hardener portion isn't present or it never got mixed in before use, you're going to have to leave it a lot longer to ensure it is fully cured before you try to do the cut/buff.

There was just one part. It's a spray can with the paint already mixed and made up........

Now that I'm not at work, it looks as though you might have swirled some product into the clear coat.

Thanks.......No, I let the clear coat dry overnight....Then I buffed with compound and then polish...........

You aren't following ... I'm telling you, the clear wasn't cured to full hardness when you did the cut/buff. It can take a few days for the paint/clear to cure hard enough to work. When you did the cut/buff, the product embedded itself into the clear causing the issues. At least that's my working theory. You may end up having to completely strip the door and redoing the paint/clear.

Ah......ok...I get you..I thought that I might have let the Meguiars polish dry i.e. I didn't wipe it off quickly enough........Is that not a possibility too? Yes, I might have to do the whole thing again!
